# Does DNS need to be pointed toward the right sever, for SSL to work

Tags: ssl, postfix, ssl-certificate, starttls

So the issue I'm having, is with a new mail server I've been setting up. Now it seems to work fine when not using ssl. And if I try using ssl, with a mail client like airmail it says host name mismatch. Now my question is could it be because our DNS is still pointing towards the old mail server.

Comment: It's easy to test. Edit your hosts file and force the resolution of the right name to the right ip. It will work. DNS does no magic here, it can be avoided or "poisoned" with the hosts file edit.

Comment: Be sure to know how to delete client's and dns cache or better, reboot.

Comment: @Marco that's a great idea, never really thought about it. But yeah not that'd surprisingly, it didn't really help. Guess I need to look elsewhere for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mail server name you have configured in your mail client (Airmail) must be the same name you have defined in your SSL certificate.

The DNS for this name should point to your new mail server IP, where you have setup this server with the certificate.

If your DNS for that name is still pointing to the old mail server, so the old mail server should also have this certificate installed and setup.

Comment: OMG Thank you so much, of course that makes sense. I've been testing it with the ip address of the new server.